# To use kiddo in cxx bridge

Tags: c++, rust, extern, kdtree

Hello I'm trying to use a rust library in C++ project by using cxx bridge.
But Cargo won't let this struct and function to be inside it.
How can I put KdTree inside cxx bridge which is provided by kiddo?

```
use kiddo::{distance::squared_euclidean, KdTree, ErrorKind};
// use time::Instant;
use csv::ReaderBuilder;
use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::error;
use std::fmt;
use std::path::Path;


#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi{
struct kdtree<'a> {
        tree: KdTree<f64, &'a Record, 2>,
    }
extern "Rust" {
        fn from_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(file_path: P) -> Result<Locations, Box<dyn error::Error>>;
    }
```

Cargo leave error message like below:

```
error[cxxbridge]: unsupported type
 ┌─ src/lib.rs:43:15
 │




 43 │         tree: KdTree<f64, &'a Record, 2>,
     │               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsupported type


  error[cxxbridge]: extern function with generic parameters is not supported yet
     ┌─ src/lib.rs:48:9
     │
  48 │         fn from_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(file_path: P) -> Result<Locations, Box<dyn error::Error>>;
     │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ extern function with generic parameters is not supported yet
```

And about configuration, I just added some dependencies in Cargo.toml like this

```
    [dependencies]
kiddo = "0.2.5"
csv = "1.2.0"
#  time = "0.3.7"
serde = "^1.0"
serde_derive = "^1.0"
corrosion = "0.0.2"
cxx = "1.0"
kdtree = "0.6"

[build-dependencies]
cxx-build = "1.0"
```

Comment: Please add a [mre]. (Including crucial things such as erro messages, configuration and *properly* formatted code which *reproduces* the error)